# How to insert parameters to command prompt when starting a program in c++?

Tags: c++, command-prompt

I have no idea how to work with command prompt. I don't even know which parameters I should write. Here's the code we were given:

```
//random example function
void KMP(const string& text, const string& sample) {
    ofstream file("iz.txt");
    file<<"Test: "<<sample;
    file.close();

}

int main(int argc, const char *const argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        return -1;
    }

    string text = inputText(argv[2]);
    string sample = argv[1];
    out.open("out.txt");

    if (!out) {
        return -2;
    }

    KMP(text, sample); //KMP algorithm function that I finished coding in my program (it would be too long to copy-paste all here), but I don't know how to call it in command prompt.
    return 0;
}
```

How can I start the program with command prompt

Comment: ***How can I start the program with command prompt*** Depends on your IDE or how you are running your program

Comment: Maybe something like `myprogram "Type sample text here" "Type text here"` if your executable was named myprogram.

Comment: The `void KMP(const string& text, const string& sample)` requires but makes no use of the the text parameter so you may want to keep the second argument on the command line short since any text you typed is thrown away.

Comment: You call the `inputText()` function in your example but never define it.

Answer (score 0):

The passing of command line arguments is not specified by the C++ language. It is specified by the shell of the operating system that you are using. Quite commonly, program's execution follows this pattern:

```
./path/to/executable argument1 argument2
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to compile the program.

In command prompt-

Go to the respective path. Now,

```
g++ /yourfilename.cpp/ -o main
```

Now to run the file,

```
./main parameter1 parameter2
```